# Docker: nginx reverse proxy and how to configure multiple services (i.e on 8080 &8081)

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I am a bit stuck with configuring multiple services where nginx is the proxy server.

running :

```
docker -v                      
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0

docker-compose -v                              
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

I want to start with this test, everything in the same docker-compose.yml-file :
link to [jwilder/nginx](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/)

1. proxy :  nginx-server (jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.7.0 , which is nginx 1.17.6)
2. container1 : httpd:2.4
3. container2 : httpd:2.4

updating my /etc/hosts before I start

1. 127.0.0.1 container1.com
2. 127.0.0.1 container2.com

Here is my **docker-compose.yml-file** (obs -> version 3.7)

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.7.0
    container_name: proxy-test
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx-proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx-proxy.conf:ro

  container1:
    image: httpd:2.4
    container_name: container-1
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST:container1.com
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  container2:
    image: httpd:2.4
    container_name: container-2
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST:container2.com
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

here is my **nginx-proxy.conf**:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     container1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    }
}

server {
  listen        80;
  server_name   container2.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:8081;
  }
}
```

After this I run the

`docker exec container-1 sed -i 's/It works!/Container 1/' /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html` **AND**

`docker exec container-2 sed -i 's/It works!/Container 2/' /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html`

---

Test 1 :   with curl to the port 8080 and port 8081

```
curl localhost:8080
response -> Container 1

curl localhost:8081 
response -> Container 2
```

Test 2 : with curl to container1.com **AND** container2.com

```
curl container1.com
status 502
curl container2.com
status 502
```

Are the settings in my conf wrong ?

Troubleshooting 1:

1. `docker exec -it proxy-test bash`
2. I can see that the nginx-proxy.conf is in the directory (/etc/nginx/conf.d)
3. /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is there as well

Troubleshooting 2: The proxy-log (`Connection refused - while connecting to upstream`)

```
proxy-test    | nginx.1    | 2020/04/03 10:52:08 [error] 61#61: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.29.0.1, server: container1.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "container1.com"
proxy-test    | nginx.1    | 2020/04/03 10:52:08 [error] 61#61: *9 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.29.0.1, server: container1.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "container1.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 solutions to this.

(1)
the first is to update the nginx-proxy.conf with the name of the containers instead of pointing to  `http://localhost:8080;` and  `http://localhost:8081;` :

new config-file

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     container1.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://container-1;
    }
}

server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   container2.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://container-2;
    }
}
```

(2)
Leaving out the nginx-proxy.conf-file , docker-compose.yml will map things correctly.